# Best way to update a table view after deleting a row with animation?

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a table view that displays the cell index in a label, so the table view might look something like:

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

I want to let the user delete a cell with an animation using:

```
tbl.deleteRows(at: [IndexPath(row: idx, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
```

But the problem is, then the other cells don't update their index labels after the animation. So if for example I deleted index 1, then after the delete animation is completed, the table ends up looking like:

```
0
2
3
4
```

What's the best way to reload the table view *after* the delete animation, since deleteRows doesn't have a completion callback?

I'm not interested in just calling `tbl.reloadData()` in place of `tbl.deleteRows(...)` since I am interested in the delete animation.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `performBatchUpdates` of `UITableView` and update the other rows upon completion:

```swift
tbl.performBatchUpdates({
    self.tbl.deleteRows(at: [IndexPath(row: idx, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
}, completion: { (done) in
    let indexPathsToUpdate = (idx...self.tbl.numberOfRows(inSection: 0)).map { IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0) }
    self.tbl.reloadRows(at: indexPathsToUpdate, with: .none)
})
```

Or can also perform these operations with `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` and the animations will happen simultaneously:

```swift
let indexPathsToUpdate = (idx+1...tbl.numberOfRows(inSection: 0)).map { IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0) }
tbl.beginUpdates()
tbl.deleteRows(at: [IndexPath(row: tbl, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
tbl.reloadSections(IndexSet(integersIn: 0...0), with: .none)
tbl.endUpdates()
```

Please note I used `reloadRows(at: indexPathsToUpdate, with: .none)` with animation `.none` as suggested, but it's up to you the way you would like them to be update, using some animation or not.